# POSTing file as a single-part document with RestKit 0.2x

Tags: objective-c, json, restkit-0.20

I would like to POST a file using RestKit 0.23.3.

I have tried some experiments with the method

```
RKObjectManager multipartFormRequestWithObject:method:path:parameters:constructingBodyWithBlock:
```

But that's not what I want.
I need to POST a file as a single part request.

```
POST /some_url HTTP/1.1
Host: ...
User-Agent: ...
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 8

test123
```

I am trying to POST this request via RestKit as the server returns a JSON object as a response.

I have also found a [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/restkit/2spIqUCNyXM) that suggests the following

```
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo, 0.75);
RKRequestSerialization *serialization = [RKRequestSerialization serializationWithData:data MIMEType:@"image/jpeg"];
[[RKClient sharedClient] put:resourcePath params:serialization delegate:self];
```

However, this snippet seems to be appropriate just for older versions of RestKit. Is tere any equivalent code for with RestKit 0.2x?

It would be fine if the MIMEType is auto-detected. My input is an instance of NSURL (imported file from iCloud).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the data you want to send and use it to create an `NSURLRequest`. You need to do all of the work to do that, but as your data is a file that should be little effort. Then create an object request operation with `objectRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:` or `managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:managedObjectContext:success:failure:` from your object manager and enqueue it.

In this way RestKit will send your request and handle any response (assuming you have configured the response descriptors etc).

Comment: Pretty straightforward. I tried to find some appropriate method in RestKit and overloked that I can crate the instance of NSURLRequest by hand. Thanks. :)